# Don't understand something in this example from Google

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to understand how to use Google Cloud messaging in my android app so I found this guild written by Google but there is something there I don't understand.

This methods suppose to return true if Google Play Services is available on the device and if not it opens the option to install/update Play Services:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Plus they overrode the `onResume()` method:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPlayServices(); 
}
```

In the `onCreate()` method of the main activity they wrote the following code:

```
if (checkPlayServices()) {
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    regid = getRegistrationId(context);

    if (regid.isEmpty()) {
        registerInBackground();
    }
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
}
```

Assuming the Google Play Services needs to be updated the variable `resultCode` will a value different from `ConnectionResult.SUCCESS` and therefore the dialog box will be creates and the return value will be false. But if the return value is false the registration process will not take place even if the use did update the Play Services.

Comment: I don't understand what you are confused about. If the connection failed, the program returns `false` because registration isn't possible (because you cannot connect to Google Cloud).

Comment: If the user updated/installed the Play Services he is now able to register, but the application will not do so because the return value is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like even though it returns false the first time through, the OnResume() method possibly fires the checkPlayService() off a second time which should return true which would happen after the user updates the Play Service.

The registration logic won't execute. As this is only a demo app to demonstrate GCM, they haven't added anything to deal with that scenario.  It appears that the assumption is that the user likely already has the Play Service present.  In that scenario, The user would have to leave the app and re-enter it. You could make a modification to the onResume() method to execute the same logic as the onCreate(), though.

Comment: The return value of the checkPlayService() in the on resume method is a different value. It's is not accessible from the onCreate method. It is not global.

Comment: correct, but if it returns false during onCreate() but the user opts to download the update through the dialog, then it should return true during onResume() after the update is performed.  If the user does not install/update the Play Service, it will continue to return false.

Comment: But how does this true that is returned during the onResume make the onCreate method execute the registration code?

Comment: It won't execute.  As this is only a demo app to demonstrate GCM, they haven't added anything to deal with that scenario.  The user would have to leave the app and re-enter it.  You could make a modification to the onResume() method to execute the same logic as the onCreate(), though.